# How to preload header images in Next 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get the page to be rendered only when the header image is finished loading in order to avoid that blank space when the image is loading.

I'm using Next.JS Image component `import Image from 'next/image'`

So I included the property "priority" like this:

```
<Image
  ...
  priority={true}
/>
```

However, it doesn't seem to have any effect. When I load the page, the blank space is still there for a while until the image is finished loading.

This ruins the animation that is executed when the page is loaded.

Comment: I think it should be used **loading = 'eager'** ...... When eager, load the image immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It could be because the image itself is a large and detailed image, and even with preloading it takes some time to actually load.

A potential workaround would be to use the `placeholder` properties on your image to render a blurred image before the actual image is loaded.

```
<Image placeholder="blur" blurDataURL="/your-URL.image" />
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#priority

Comment: This workaround doesn't solve the problem :(